# How to make corrections to a git project created in a wrong directory -- if it is one level up and that means it includes other repos?

Tags: git

If I have a directory called `code`, inside my home directory:

```
~/code
```

and then there are tiny projects, and each one is a git repository with the remote repo on either github or gitlab:

```
~/code/TryAngularJS
~/code/TryReactJS
```

Now I created a `TryNodeJS` project, but mistakenly, instead of being inside of

```
~/code/TryNodeJS
```

and do

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:mike/TryNodeJS.git
git add .
git commit
```

I actually did it in `~/code`, which is one level up.  So in other words, I created a repo that includes other tiny repos.

In this case, how do I fix / correct the mistake from this point on?

I think I have to do things on the local computer as well as on gitlab because I already `git remote add`? (I didn't `git push -u origin master` yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Delete the .git folder in the root folder
- cd into the inner folder where you want git to be
- git init again with the script that you just posted above.

  ```
  // Delete wrong git folder
  rm -rf ~/code/.git

  // go into the right folder
  cd ~/code/TryNodeJS

  // init it as git repository
  git init

  // Add origin (remote)
  git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:mike/TryNodeJS.git

  // add and commit all files
  git add .

  // Commit the changes.
  git commit
  ```

---

> I think I have to do things on the local computer as well as on gitlab ...
>     (I didn't git push -u origin master yet)

Since you did not pushed yet there is no code on the remote so no harm was done.
Simlpy create the git project in the new location and you are good to commit and push

---

#### if yo ualready pushed (which you did not)

In this case you simply need to overwrite the remote data with the `-f` flag

```
// Overwrite any existing data in the remote server
git push origin -f master
```

Comment: I think it makes sense... although I am not that familiar with git in this situation yet to know for sure.  You might want to make the comments to begin with `#` so that it can be harmless if pasted into the shell